# Whats the best router for 4 machines?

Tags: networking, router, adsl

I have an ADSL with 4 public static IP Addresses. I wish to hide my larger network behind another router what is the best way to do this? I don't want to use a PC with 2 NICS but ideally I want it fire walled and provide NAT addressing to the other network.

I've seen a few cheap routers but don't know if they are any good.

Any recommendations for cheap green solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into Sonicwall products. They look to do everything you're hoping to do (and more)

We have a switch / Firewall combo which has done quite well for us. It's quite easy to set up firewall rules, monitor traffic, and you can easily set up a VPN as well.

http://www.sonicwall.com/

Comment: Very easy to manage, with wizard-style setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a supported solution I know Cisco ASAs like the ASA5505 will do this. I'm sure there's others, but I don't typically deal with them.

I also know an old PC with m0n0wall or pfSense will do this as well. Or you can even spring for a SBC (like the Alix by PC Engines or a Soekris board) and roll your own little router.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a business, I suggest going with a more business oriented solution that has some level or support (unless you feel confident enough to troubleshoot issues yourself). Something like a Sonicwall as mentioned by dknuckles should do the trick, or even Cisco's small business routers like the ones from this page should suffice:

http://www.cisco.com/cisco/web/solutions/small_business/products/routers_switches/small_business_routers/index.html

A Cisco ASA5505 is a very powerful router, so it may be overkill for just 4 machines. If you plan to scale though, this may be a better solution and investment upfront.